# 4 circles tangent to each other

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given three positive real numbers $r_1,r_2,r_3\in\mathbb{R}$, what is the necessary and sufficient condition that when I take 3 circles each tangent to each other of radii $r_1,r_2,r_3$ respectively, there is a circle bounding all of them and tangent to all of them?

For example, if $r_1=r_2=r_3$ then I can always find such a circle, however if $r_1=r_2$ and $r_1>r_3$ then it seems like it is not possible to find such a circle.

[image: The image in my mind is something like this. I want to guarantee the existence of the cirlce passing through A,B and C]

Comment: I think what you want can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem#Definition_of_curvature

Comment: I think you are right, Descartes' theorem should somehow solve my problem but maybe you can clarify something. If $r_1=r_2=100$ and $r_3=1$, there are two solutions for the curvature of the fourth circle, one of them is negative and the other one is positive. What does this mean? Is there a big circle tangent to all three of them or not?